# Web one line address search

Tags: skmaps

We already have an API key because we use Skobbler maps on other products.
We have another iOS app that uses Apple maps and we would like to know if we can make a http / https request for address search. In this case we do not want to include SKMaps framework.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Right now this is not possible - the search API is only exposed in the mobile SDKs (not via a web REST API).